# Follow object in 3D

Tags: math, 3d, directx, transformation

I'm in a bit of a problem here and I would like some help. I'm trying to find a rotation that allows me to make an object follow the player ( face it at all times ).
I first tried doing the cross product, the dot and rotating, but that just doesn't work correctly.
I then proceeded to decompose it into two rotations ( yaw and pitch ) and locked-out roll. It now works, but just for some directions ( I believe a quarter of a circle, but could be less ).
This is my current code:

```
    XMVECTOR newDir = Vec3DtoDX((Player->Position - InternalEntity->Position).getNormalized());
    XMVECTOR orig = XMVectorSet(0,0,1,0);

    XMVECTOR xNewDir,xOrigDir,yNewDir,yOrigDir;
    xOrigDir = XMVectorSet(0,1,0,0); // (y,z)
    yOrigDir = XMVectorSet(0,1,0,0); // (x,z)

    xNewDir = XMVectorSet(newDir.m128_f32[1],newDir.m128_f32[2],0,0);
    yNewDir = XMVectorSet(newDir.m128_f32[0],newDir.m128_f32[2],0,0);

    float xAngle = XMVector2AngleBetweenVectors(xNewDir,xOrigDir).m128_f32[0];
    float yAngle = XMVector2AngleBetweenVectors(yNewDir,yOrigDir).m128_f32[0];

    XMVECTOR rotDX = XMQuaternionRotationRollPitchYaw(xAngle,yAngle,0);
    PxQuat rot = VecDXto4D<PxQuat>(rotDX);
```

Here's working correctly, if I face the object close to the Z axis
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSYoi.jpg

And if I move more, it turns, something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ4m0.jpg

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:
I allready tried to create the quaternion from the cross and the angle from the acos of the dot. In fact, it was my first though. The problem is that it doesn't work correctly. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
    PxVec3 newDir = (Player->Position - InternalEntity->Position).getNormalized();

    PxVec3 orig(0,0,1);

    PxVec3 axis = newDir.cross(orig);

    float angle = XMVector3AngleBetweenVectors(Vec3DtoDX(newDir),Vec3DtoDX(orig)).m128_f32[0];

    PxQuat rot(angle,axis);
```

where XMVector3AngleBetweenVectors is:

```
  XMVECTOR L1 = XMVector3ReciprocalLength(V1);
  XMVECTOR L2 = XMVector3ReciprocalLength(V2);

  XMVECTOR Dot = XMVector3Dot(V1, V2);

  L1 = XMVectorMultiply(L1, L2);

  XMVECTOR CosAngle = XMVectorMultiply(Dot, L1);
  CosAngle = XMVectorClamp(CosAngle, g_XMNegativeOne.v, g_XMOne.v);

  return XMVectorACos(CosAngle);
```

This results in the following screens:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYu19.jpg
And : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHvxr.jpg

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after a lot of trouble, here's a working code:

```
// Using PxExtendedVec3 to use double
// For ground enemies, just flatten the positions across the Up vector ( set y to 0  in this case )
PxExtendedVec3 newDir = Vec3Dto3D<PxExtendedVec3>(Vec3Dto3D<PxExtendedVec3>(Player->Position) - Vec3Dto3D<PxExtendedVec3>(InternalEntity->Position));
newDir.y = 0;
newDir.normalize();
PxExtendedVec3 orig(0,0,1);
PxExtendedVec3 axis = newDir.cross(orig);

double angle = -asin(_Core::Clamp<double>(axis.magnitude(),-1.0,1.0));
axis.normalize();
// Compensate the [-pi/2,pi/2] range of asin
if(newDir.dot(Vec3Dto3D<PxVec3>(orig)) < 0.0)
    angle = XM_PIDIV2 - angle + XM_PIDIV2;//angle += XM_PI/2.0;

PxQuat rot(angle,Vec3Dto3D<PxVec3>(axis));
```

Where PxExtendedVec3 is a vector of doubles, XM_PIDIV2 is pi / 2:
Hope this helps somebody, I've been with this for a long time.

EDIT: A little comment. I set Y to 0 in this case, as that removes some unwanted roll, but consider that that line is optional, so play with it if you like. Also, this gives ABSOLUTE rotations, not relative to the last rotation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to know the vector that defines the plane of the object that you want to be facing to the viewer. Let's say this vector is 'forward'. Usually this vector could be the local z axis vector in the object space converted to world space.

Once you have this vector you have to find de rotation axis:

axis = CrossProduct( newDir, forward )

and the angle of rotation:

angle = acos( DotProduct( newDir, forward ) )

where all vectors must be unitary.

Once you have the angle and the axis, just calculate the quaternion defining this rotation. You can do it using a API function like: RotationAxis or building the quaternion from scratch.

Finally, once you have the quaternion, just rotate your object using it.

Comment: The problem is that you are using always the same orig vector and it should change as the rotation of the object changes. You have to transform this orig vector using model to world matrix.

Comment: But if I transform the orig to world space, wouldn't I need to multiply with the previous rotation, as it would be relative to the previous orientation?

Comment: I tried that, and also tried multiplying with the previous, and still no good results.